# @JsonAutoDetect immutable objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

Есть класс:

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Payer {

    private Long Id;
    private Long companyId;
    private String name;

    public void setId(Long Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(Long companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
}
```

И в таком виде все работает, но как его сделать immutable, избегая маппинга в конструкторе? Возможно как-то использовать `@JsonAutoDetect`?

```
public class Payer {

    private final Long Id;
    private final Long companyId;
    private final String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public PayerDto(@JsonProperty("") Long id, 
                    @JsonProperty("") Long companyId, 
                    @JsonProperty("") String name) {
        Id = id;
        this.companyId = companyId;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Для этого нужно скомпилировать исходный код компилятором версии 8+ с ключом `-parameters` и использовать соответствующее расширение Jackson. Без такой компиляции байткод просто не будет содержать информацию об именах параметров конструктора (почему и необходимо писать эти имена полностью в аннотации).

Comment: Убрать `public` сеттеры и оставить только геттеры. Добавить конструктор с параметрами для создания объектов в своём коде и конструктор без параметров для Jackson'а.

Comment: @AlexChermenin и вы предлагаете убрать модификатор `final`?

Comment: @JVic да, придётся убрать

Comment: @etki оформите пожалуйста как ответ, я отмечу верным

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать lombock то можно сделать так:

```
@Builder()
@Data
@JsonDeserialize(builder = PayerDto.PayerDtoBuilder.class)
public static class PayerDto {
    private final Long id;
    private final Long companyId;
    private final String name;
    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class PayerDtoBuilder {
    }
}
```